# confidence interval calculation and z score

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I have these 2 examples:

[image]

and

[image]

in step 1 of solution, for the first one we have 1-0.9 but for the second one we just have 0.95

Why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referring to different z-tables.

The first uses $P(z>z_0)=\frac{1-0.9}{2}=0.05$, while the second uses $P(0<z<z_0)=\frac{0.95}{2}=0.475$.

For example, refer to the table:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

It is $P(0<z<1.96)=0.475$ and $P(z>1.96)=0.025$.

Comment: How should I find out which area (between mean and z) or (beyond Z) I should choose? because both of these questions are the same but they considered different area!

Comment: Confidence interval (given by confidence level) is always the central interval on the normal curve (within plus-minus standard error). One minus confidence level is the outside intervals on the normal curve (given by non-confidence level or error term $\alpha$). Both tables should give the same critical value (or z-score), for example, in the above example $z_0=1.96$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why when I tried to find the z value between z and mean was different from beyond z. maybe I tried to find out the value from wrong chart

Answer (score 0):

The first is asking for a $90\%$ confidence interval, the other for a $95\%$ confidence interval.

Comment: Ok, but why we have 1-0.9 in first step of question 1? why dont we have 1-.95 for the second one too?